# type errors with linked list pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

ok so long story short. im having trouble with a multifile linked list and its pointers...
The code includes several files: prog10.h, createFile.c, main.c,release memory.c, and the piece of the code that i am supposed to be completing, p10.c

The files are as follows

1. prog10.h

   ```
   #include<stdio.h> 
   #include<stdlib.h> 
   typedef struct person
   {
      char name[20];
      int age; 
      struct person *next_ptr;
   } PERSON;

   PERSON* createList(void);
   void print_list(PERSON *head); 
   void release_memory(PERSON*);
   ```
2. createFile.c

   ```
     #include "prog10.h"
     PERSON* createList()
     {
         char answer; 
         PERSON *current, *previous, *head = NULL;
         while(1) 
        {
           printf("Add a person to the list? [y/n] ");
           scanf("%c", &answer);
           if(answer == 'n') 
              return head; 

           current = (PERSON*)malloc(sizeof(PERSON)); 

           printf("Enter a Name: ");
           scanf("%s", current->name);
           printf("Enter person's age: "); 
           scanf("%i", &current->age);              

         }
     }
   ```
3. main.c

   ```
   #include "prog10.h"
   int main(void)
   {
      PERSON *head = NULL;
      head = createList();
      print_list(head);
      release_memory(head); 

      printf("Done\n");
      return 0;
   }
   ```
4. releaseMemory.c

   ```
   #include "prog10.h"
   void release_memory(PERSON *person *person_ptr)
   {
      PERSON *tmp_next_ptr;
      while(person_ptr != NULL)
      {
         tmp_next_ptr = person_ptr->next_ptr;
         free(person_ptr);
         person_ptr = tmp_next_ptr;
      }    
      puts("Memory Released");
   }
   ```
5. p10.c

   ```
   #include "prog10.h"
   void print_list(PERSON *person_ptr)
   {
      while(ptr != NULL)
      {
         printf("Name = %s\n", ptr->name);
         printf("Age = %i\n", ptr->age);

         ptr = ptr->next_ptr;
      }
   }
   ```

I know it probably seems obvious to one more experienced than I, but why is this not running? please help, i'm really lost, and need to figure this out for an assignment/finals :b

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: in releaseMemory.c you have a problem with your parameter. Should be `PERSON *person_ptr` instead of `PERSON *person *person_ptr`...although of course there may be other issues as well

Comment: in createFile.c, [don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) And in p10.c, you use `while(ptr != NULL)` but you've never declared `ptr` anywhere in the code.

Comment: Your `createList()` function never assigns a value to head (aside from initializing with null).  Actually, it creates new nodes but doesn't add them to the list at all.

Answer (score 1):

Okay despite the issues with this question, after looking through I feel I should compile my comments into an answer of sorts. So here goes...

### We'll start with an easy one.

[Don't typecast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

### I think you are not understanding correctly how to use struct names and struct typedefs as a data type.

If you create a struct like this: `typedef struct person{...}PERSON;` when you use PERSON as a type for a parameter, and you want a struct pointer, you will do it like this: `func(PERSON *person_ptr)`. PERSON is the type in this case, * indicates we want a pointer to this struct, and person_ptr is the name of the struct.

### Be wary of variable names.

You use ptr in one function where this variable is neither a parameter or declared local or global variable. You should be getting an error there indicating that ptr has not been defined. And be mindful of the names you give variables. When you name a variable, make it something that you can just look at and understand the meaning without comments, or if necessary, provide comments so that it is precise what the variable is meant for.

### Your createList doesn't do what it is intended to do.

In your create list you are not actually creating a list, you are simply creating a bunch of head nodes and returning <strike>the last one you created</strike> **NULL**. You must remember when creating nodes that you need to attach them to the end of the previous node (or in front of the previous node, depending on your implementation of the list and what its purpose is).

When you are creating nodes in a list, remember to link them together (and don't forget not to lose anything in the process). You create up to **N** number of nodes, but you lose every single one of them because you never chain them together with the `next_ptr`

This is a start to the answer, but I don't want to rewrite the code for you simply because I feel there is value in trial and error when learning about things like Abstract Data Types. Work on the code a bit and if you are still having issues, edit your question. And if you do this, try to be concise to the problem. Don't feel the need to post every last bit of your code.

Comment: Actually, his `createList()` doesn't even return the last node he created.  Just NULL, since he never sets `head`.

Comment: True, but that's just the tip of the iceberg. But thanks for pointing that out, I knew in such a long compilation answer I'd miss a small (albeit important) detail. Corrected.

Comment: ok thank you for the help. I have one more question: when declaring ptr, what type would you suggest declaring it as?

Comment: well when you say `typedef struct person {...} PERSON` what that says is allow `PERSON` to stand in place of `struct person` so since you did this, use `PERSON` to stand for the type of `struct person`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help guys, it turns out that because of an error in my notes that i failed to see because i am (obviously) new at this, the answer was a lot simpler than i ever would have thought. Because of the embarrassingly obvious nature of my error, I would not post an update but for the fact that somebody else might someday make this mistake. so without further ado, here is the updated version of p10.c:

```
    #include "prog10.h" 
    void print_list(PERSON *person_ptr)
    {
       while(person_ptr != NULL
       {
          printf("Name: %s\n", person_ptr -> name);
          printf("Age: %i\n", person_ptr -> age);
          person_ptr = person_ptr -> nest_ptr);
       }
    }
```

Again, thank you for your help and have a good day!